# Matrix configuration in Jenkins generate weird workspace from SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have recently begun experimenting with Jenkins, and I'm either very mistaken about what matrix configuration jobs are supposed to do, or I am doing something wrong. I have tried looking for similar questions already asked, but I'm not familiar enough with jenkins jargon yet to have found any. Perhaps this is the first time anyone has ever asked!

I have a project checked into svn that has a directory structure like this:

```
./doc
./include/
./src/
./target
./target/linux-ARM
./target/linux-ARM/include
./target/linux-ARM/lib
./target/linux-ARM/src
./target/linux-i386
./target/linux-i386/include
./target/linux-i386/lib
./target/linux-i386/src
./target/linux-x86_64
./target/linux-x86_64/include
./target/linux-x86_64/lib
./target/linux-x86_64/src
./target/win32-i386
./target/win32-i386/include
./target/win32-i386/lib
./target/win32-i386/src
./target/win32-x86_64
./target/win32-x86_64/include
./target/win32-x86_64/lib
./target/win32-x86_64/src
```

the platform-independent code is inside ./src and all platform-specific code are in the appropriate target directories. I specifically made this directory structure so that I could use the matrix-configuration project in jenkins.

The only axis I define is called "platform" and it has the values: linux-ARM, linux-i386, linux-x86_64, win32-i386 and win32-x86_64.

I thought I could simply specify the following buildstep, and everything would be taken care of:

```
chmod 777 ./target/$platform/build
chmod 777 ./target/$platform/deploy
./target/$platform/build
./target/$platform/deploy
```

Now the thing is, jenkins does this job properly and doesn't report any errors; but when I navigate (inside jenkins) to the workspace section, I see that an entirely different directory structure was used to build the project. Basically the entire project is exported anew for every configuration and is placed inside the ./$platform directory.

```
./doc // <--- this one is actually thesame
./include/
./platform/
./platform/linux-ARM
./platform/linux-ARM/doc // <--- as this one
./platform/linux-ARM/include
./platform/linux-ARM/src
./platform/linux-ARM/target
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-ARM
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-ARM/include
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-ARM/lib
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-ARM/src
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-i386
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-i386/include
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-i386/lib
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-i386/src
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-x86_64
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-x86_64/include
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-x86_64/lib
./platform/linux-ARM/target/linux-x86_64/src
...
...
./src/
./target
./target/linux-ARM
./target/linux-ARM/include
./target/linux-ARM/lib
./target/linux-ARM/src
./target/linux-i386
./target/linux-i386/include
./target/linux-i386/lib
./target/linux-i386/src
./target/linux-x86_64
./target/linux-x86_64/include
./target/linux-x86_64/lib
./target/linux-x86_64/src
./target/win32-i386
./target/win32-i386/include
./target/win32-i386/lib
./target/win32-i386/src
./target/win32-x86_64
./target/win32-x86_64/include
./target/win32-x86_64/lib
./target/win32-x86_64/src
```

I can't imagine that this is intended behaviour. Yet as long as jenkins claims the project is fine, I'm not one to complain. It becomes a problem however when you want to generate docs using doxygen. Doxygen will include the alien ./$platform directories in its recursive scan, and will try to parse documentation of 6 exactly the same source files in different locations.

Is there any way to get around this? I see no reason to export the same project 6 times. Or is this intended behaviour and should I switch to using 5 seperate free style jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins always does that for matrix jobs. I think the reason is that they should have independent workspaces, so the builds don't influence each other.

You could solve your Doxygen-problem by excluding the platform-folder in your `Doxyfile`, or by only running Doxygen for one of the subjobs.

Comment: thx, I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong or if it's supposed to work that way.